# html input in Next.js app only allowing English input

Tags: next.js

I am workng on Next js app. App was developed by **prev developer** in English and now I have added chinese translation to it. I am facing an issue when I add input field. It is not allowing multi-language input. If I type in English, it works fine, if I type any other language, nothing gets typed.
I tried simple input for testing. such as

```
<input type="text"/>
```

similarly,

```
<input type="text" onChange={e=>setName(e.target.value)} value={name} />
```

Both of them type English only.
Note: If I copy paste other language text, it works! Also same inputs work in other next.js apps.

I tried finding solution on the Internet but no Luck

Answer (score 0):

It was not an issue of Next js, It was related to Metamask mobile App. It is the one restricting the language input. I tried it in chrome and it works fine. (I couldn't do it earlier because it is dapp)